# Replacing innerHTML in every keyup is extremely slow in FireFox

Tags: html, dom, innerhtml

My script is just to display how many number of characters left to type.
So every keyup html of, `<span class="number">150</span>` is replaced with available number by using jquery's html().
I've tried [this way](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml) but still getting extremely slow in FF.
Is there any other method to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try using `textContent` instead

Comment: can you post some code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input>` instead of `<span>` - just style it properly and than use jQuery `$('#myInput').val()`.